# Não consigo habilitar OPCache no PHP 5.6.30

Tags: php

Estou usando Ubuntu 16.04 e compilei o PHP 5.6.30 usando a flag --enable-opcache, mesmo não sendo necessário nesta versão.

No php.ini, eu já adicionei as linhas

```
zend_extension=caminho_do_opcache.so
opcache.enable=1
```

Também já tentei configurar no php.ini o `opcache.error_log` mas nenhuma mensagem foi logada neste arquivo.

Estas e outras opções que eu testei não habilitaram o OP Cache, nenhuma delas exibiu a seção **Zend OPCache** no `phpinfo()`.

- Como eu posso habilita-lo?
- Existe a chance de ele estar habilitado e não aparecer no `phpinfo()`?
- Será que eu esqueci alguma etapa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri que o php não estava lendo o php.ini que eu estava alterado, o que é bem estranho porque não há outro php.ini no sistema inteiro.

Para resolver, eu criei um link simbólico no diretório especificado la no `phpinfo` **Configuration File (php.ini) Path** apontando para o php.ini que eu estava alterando, reiniciei o php-fpm e agora OPCache está habilitado.